# where is the real implementation of Int32 in .net-core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have cloned the code of dotnet core from github, and want to read the src code about System.Int32, but I find out that the code of Int32 is really so strange.

```
public partial struct Int32 : System.IComparable, System.IComparable<int>, System.IConvertible, System.IEquatable<int>, System.IFormattable
{
    public const int MaxValue = 2147483647;
    public const int MinValue = -2147483648;
    public int CompareTo(int value) { return default(int); }
    public bool Equals(int obj) { return default(bool); }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { return default(bool); }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return default(int); }
    public static int Parse(string s) { return default(int); }
    public static int Parse(string s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style) { return default(int); }
    public static int Parse(string s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(int); }
    public static int Parse(string s, System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(int); }
    int System.IComparable.CompareTo(object value) { return default(int); }
    System.TypeCode System.IConvertible.GetTypeCode() { return default(System.TypeCode); }
    bool System.IConvertible.ToBoolean(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(bool); }
    byte System.IConvertible.ToByte(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(byte); }
    char System.IConvertible.ToChar(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(char); }
    System.DateTime System.IConvertible.ToDateTime(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(System.DateTime); }
    decimal System.IConvertible.ToDecimal(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(decimal); }
    double System.IConvertible.ToDouble(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(double); }
    short System.IConvertible.ToInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(short); }
    int System.IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(int); }
    long System.IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(long); }
    sbyte System.IConvertible.ToSByte(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(sbyte); }
    float System.IConvertible.ToSingle(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(float); }
    object System.IConvertible.ToType(System.Type type, System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(object); }
    ushort System.IConvertible.ToUInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(ushort); }
    uint System.IConvertible.ToUInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(uint); }
    ulong System.IConvertible.ToUInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(ulong); }
    public override string ToString() { return default(string); }
    public string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(string); }
    public string ToString(string format) { return default(string); }
    public string ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider provider) { return default(string); }
    public static bool TryParse(string s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.IFormatProvider provider, out int result) { result = default(int); return default(bool); }
    public static bool TryParse(string s, out int result) { result = default(int); return default(bool); }
}
```

All the methods of Int32 just return the default value, so where can I find the real implementation of System.Int32?

Comment: Can you link to where you found the source code?

Comment: The `ref` subdirectories (e.g. src/System.Runtime/`ref`/System.Runtime.cs) are for the reference assemblies (a.k.a "contracts"). They merely define the public API which the compiler uses to determine what is callable.  The implementation is always under a  `src` directory (e.g. src/System.Linq/`src`/...).  If there's no src directory then the real code is in a different library, and frequently that library comes from the coreclr project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost every data type in .net is a part of **CLR**, hence you can find the implementation of datatypes in coreclr project.

[CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime)

In the project, I found the implementation of `System.Int32` at this link.
[System.Int32 source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Int32.cs)

I think, this is what you want.